# Align to center in Sketch ignoring pixel snap

Tags: sketch-app

I want to have this Cog in the exact horizontal middle of the symbol. How can I achieve this? Using align-center keeps snapping the object to whole pixels

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Sketch 55.x :**

Go to `Preferences` → `Layers` → Uncheck `Pixel Fitting : Fit layers and points to pixel bounds`

[image: Sketch preferences options]

After That, try to center your shape again, it should now work.